# Ubuntu 20.04 expereancing heavy lag

Tags: ssd

yesterday i upgraded to a bigger SSD and since then the whole System is laggy as hell. I can't even watch youtube videos, they have like 1-2 FPS. Not even the window animations are fluid.

I moved from a 250GB M.2 SSD to a 1TB one (ddrescue -v --force /dev/sda /dev/sdb) and before that I upgraded  from 20.04 to 20.04.1 (but idk if thats the problem)

I use a chuwi aerobook and now even typing this text feels laggy.
The CPU usage is as low as 10% and the RAM is far from full (i have no swap), so i can't find any reason for this behavior.

I already thank you for any hints or solutions and ignoring my bad english.

Comment: Have you looked at "System Monitor" to see whats consuming your resources? I have used ubuntu on this same machine since before Meerkat without any issues it has to be a configuration or other software problem

Comment: Try adding the output of `grep SwapTotal /proc/meminfo` to your question (edit the question).

Comment: i dont have a swap (nor a swapfile). In systemmonitor nothing is using anything at all. ram is at 2.6 GB (of 8) and cpu is at 10-15%